# MySQL Update DATETIME to DATE

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-update

I have a large table with a `DATETIME` column and for index reasons I want to add a column which just contains a DATE type. It seems that MySQL is not able to use an index by the following expression `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)` therefore I want to add another column with a second index.

For updating I use this simple statement:

```
UPDATE table SET datecol = DATE(datetimecol)
```

Now a strange behavior occurs: the `datecol-column` contains the correct values. But the `datetimecolumn` changes as well: to the current `timestamp`. This is the default value for this column.

I'm working now for many years with databases and MySQL but I cannot explain this behavior.

The current version is `MySQL 5.1.66-0`.

Do you have any suggestions or explanations for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `datetimecol` is not of type `DATETIME`, but of type `TIMESTAMP` which (by default) has the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` attribute that [automatically updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) to the current time when a record is modified.

> To suppress automatic properties for the first `TIMESTAMP` column, do either of the following:
>
> - Define the column with a `DEFAULT` clause that specifies a constant default value.
> - Specify the `NULL` attribute. This also causes the column to permit `NULL` values, which means that you cannot assign the current timestamp by setting the column to `NULL`. Assigning `NULL` sets the column to `NULL`.

Therefore:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
  MODIFY datetimecol TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

To update the records this one time without altering the values in `datetimecol`, you should explicitly set them to their incumbent values:

```
UPDATE my_table SET
  datetimecol = datetimecol,
  datecol     = DATE(datetimecol);
```

Comment: Well, this works! Thank you very much :)

But why is MySQL trying to update this column at all? For me this is not obvious by my own statement.

Comment: @fire: Is that not explained in the first paragraph of my answer above (and especially the manual page to which it links)?

Comment: :( Sorry yes, I'm always confused by this datatype... sorry for that.

I'm usually working with PostgreSQL...

Thank you again!!! :)